# Embeded flash SWF not playing on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, actionscript-3, flash

I'm new to ADOBE Animate CC. I recently create a flash.swf file on the animate CC and embed on html to run on Chrome. But movie not loaded error is popping up. Below are my codes. Help Needed.

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="550" height="400" id="Trial1" align="middle">
    <param name="movie" value="Trial1.swf"/>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="Trial1.swf" width="550" height="400">
        <param name="movie" value="Trial1.swf"/>
    <!--<![endif]-->
        <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
            <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player"/>
        </a>
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    </object>
    <!--<![endif]-->
</object>
```

Comment: Publish SWF+HTML with your IDE, it should work in all the browsers.

Comment: Is your swf file named `Trial1.swf` and put in the same folder of the html file?

Comment: Hi  shuizhongyuemin , yes my swf file is in the same folder as the html file

Comment: Are you sore that chrome does not blocked flash player plugin?

Comment: What error is pooping up and where? Are you able to open your swf directly - entering yourpage.com/Trial1.swf in address bar? Is something else displayed in your page? The chrome by default is now blocking flash content if it  thinks it's not crucial content (not much things on page expect .swf) In this case you should see notification icon in address bar. You can change this by entering "chrome://settings/content" > scroll to "Flash".